# To find the centre of symmetry of the curve

Tags: analytic-geometry, symmetry

Find the center of symmetry $(x_0,y_0)$ of curve $3x^2+y^2-2x+5y+2=0$.

Deduce that $x_0+y_0$ is one of these :  -2.167, -2.104, -2.055, -2.011, -1.953.

I tried to solve this question but I couldn't solve I'm confused.Can you help me how to solve this question?

First of all I wrote $3x^2+y^2-2x+5y+2=0$ under the form 3$(x^2-2x/3)+5(y^2/5+y)=-2$, and at last $3(x-1/3)^2-1/9+5(y^2/5+5)=-2$. But I can't finish it.

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: First of all I wrote 3x^2+y^2-2x+5y+2=0    then                                             3(x^2-2/3x)+5(y^2/5+y)=-2   and last 3(x-1/3)^2-1/9+5(I couldn't find here)

Comment: To ask a good question, _edit_ the question to show your work (do not just add it in comments), as well as to show the original question so we do not have to follow a link to see it. So that people can read the question better, format it according to the advice on this page: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I don´t know what has to be done in this excercise but $3(x^2-\frac23 x)=3(x^2-\frac23 x+\frac19)-\color{red}{\frac13}=3(x-\frac13)^2-\frac13$. Btw what is the meaning of the table ?

Comment: @David K I have edited the question (in the spirit of your advices) in order to show the OP how to do it for another time.

Comment: okay Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

If you could get the equation to finally look like
$$
p(x-h)^2 + q(y-k)^2 + r = 0 \tag1
$$
where $r < 0$ then you would know you had the equation of an ellipse
and you would know where its center is.
And if $r > 0$ then you would know you had the equation of a hyperbola
and you still would know where its center of symmetry is.

To convert $Ax^2 + By^2 + Cx + Dy + F = 0$ into an equation like $(1)$,
we can "complete the square" for $x$ to get the $p(x-h)^2$ term
and then complete the square for $y$ to get the $q(y-k)^2$ term.
While doing this we get some extra constant terms to add to $F$.

You seem to have the idea how to complete the square for $x$, because
you managed to write $3\left(x-\frac13\right)^2$,
which looks like $p(x-h)^2$, as desired.
You made one error while doing this, because
$$
3\left(x^2-\frac23\right) \neq 3\left(x-\frac13\right)^2 - \frac19
$$
What is actually true is that
$$
\left(x^2-\frac23\right) = \left(x-\frac13\right)^2 - \frac19
$$
and therefore
$$
3\left(x^2-\frac23\right) = 3\left(\left(x-\frac13\right)^2 - \frac19\right)
= 3\left(x-\frac13\right)^2 - \frac13
$$
But that just affects the value of the constant term 
(the one I showed as $r$ above), which may affect the shape of your
curve but will not affect where its center of symmetry is.

The real source of difficulty for you seems to be
how to complete the square for $y$.
Notice that when you started to complete the square for $x$,
you first took the terms $3x^2 - 2x$ and factored the $3$ out of the
$x^2$ term to get $3\left(x^2-\frac23\right)$.
And now it is not too hard to see how to apply the formula
$x^2 + 2b = (x+b)^2 - b^2$ with $b = -\frac13$.
But when you looked at $y^2 + 5y$, for some reason you decided
to factor the $5$ out of the $y$ term, rather than use the coefficient
of the $y^2$ term.
Since the coefficient of the $y^2$ term is $1$, completing the
square would have been easier if you had not tried to factor out
any coefficients at all!

Try and see what happens if you write $y^2 + 5y$
instead of $5\left(\dfrac{y^2}5 + y\right)$ in the first few steps of
your work.